# Can't load ui-bootstrap

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, angularjs

I created a simple `AngularJS` page but it fails to load because of `UI Bootstrap`. The HTML code is:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en" ng-app="myapp">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>My HTML File</title>
    <script src="lib/angular/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="lib/angular/angular-ui-router.js"></script>
    <script src="lib/angular/ui-bootstrap-0.4.0.js"></script>
    <script src="lib/angular/angular-strap.js"></script>

    <script src="js/app.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div ui-view="headerView"></div>
    <div ui-view="navigationView"></div>
    <div ui-view="contentView"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

The error in `Chrome` is:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token < ui-bootstrap-0.4.0.js:3
```

The error in `Firebug`:

```
SyntaxError: syntax error
[Break On This Error]   

<!DOCTYPE html>

ui-boo....4.0.js (line 3
```

I did no modification on `UI Bootstrap` javascript file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried switching the order of your js files like so?

```
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>My HTML File</title>
    <script src="js/app.js"></script>
    <script src="lib/angular/ui-bootstrap-0.4.0.js"></script>
    <script src="lib/angular/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="lib/angular/angular-ui-router.js"></script>
    <script src="lib/angular/angular-strap.js"></script>
</head>
```

Could that fix it?

Comment: No it does not fix the issue. Putting `app.js` first introduces another error because `angular` is not loaded. My `app.js` is `
var myapp = angular.module('myapp', ['ui.state', 'ui.bootstrap']);`

Comment: Console log with your file order: Uncaught ReferenceError: angular is not defined app.js:10
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token < lib/angular/ui-bootstrap-0.4.0.js:3
Uncaught Error: No module: myapp angular.js:1124

Comment: Could you please post your ui-bootstrap-0.4.0.js?

Comment: Because I think it has to do with a `<` in your code, that doesn't belong there.

Comment: You're right I did a `Save File As` to download `ui-bootstrap`, and I actually downloaded a HTML page instead of the actual javascript.